# How to use Twitter gem in Rails, need small to figure out the whole thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rubygems

I got access for the user using twitter_auth gem. Here is the code for that.

```
def twitter
  client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
  :consumer_key => '******',
  :consumer_secret => '********'
 )
 request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => new_user_url)
 session[:request_token] = request_token
 redirect_to request_token.authorize_url
end


def new
   client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
      :consumer_key => '*****',
      :consumer_secret => '******'
      )
      access_token = client.authorize(
      session[:request_token].token,
      session[:request_token].secret,
      :oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier]
      )
   #For testing purpose, i tried posting a status and its working perfectly fine

 client.update('I am authorized')
end
```

**I am confused** in using [twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) cause every example from the docs says:

```
     Twitter.user("sferik").location // throws an error, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized: Invalid / expired Token
```

From [friends and followers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/2.0.2/Twitter/Client/FriendsAndFollowers)

```
    Twitter.accept("sferik") // throws an error, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized: Invalid / expired Token
    Twitter.follow("sferik") // throws an error, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized: Invalid / expired Token
```

All these errors makes sense, cause we are applying these methods on Class not an object. But how to create an object for this. I have a authorized user but how to take actions on his profile using token we got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `client` instead of `Twitter`.

You can see [here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/) how you should do it.