# Why is the twitter oauth access token invalid / expired (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past three days but to no avail. All I'm looking to do is allow users who logged in using Twitter to tweet to their accounts.

Here's the error message that I'm trying to resolve:

```
Twitter::Error::Unauthorized in PostsController#create
Invalid or expired token
```

I've tried all sorts of different things but I came back a full 360 circle to the same message.

Here's where I'm at right now:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   def twitter
    unless @twitter_user
      provider = Authentication.find_by_provider('twitter')
      @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:token => provider.token, :secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
    end
    @twitter_user
    end
```

Here's where the error is thrown

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        twitter.update(@post.content)
    end
```

Here's how the schema is laid out

```
create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "token"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
```

Here's my initializer

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  configure do |config|
    config.path_prefix = '/auth'
  end

  provider :twitter, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.oauth_token = :token
  config.oauth_token_secret = :secret
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Didn't you asked the same question today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964676/twittererrorunauthorized-in-postscontrollercreate-invalid-or-expired-toke

Comment: I tried all of the methods posted in that thread plus more and I'm really hoping to solve this soon. That was posted yesterday

Comment: Did you confirmed that the credentials you're using are actually valid?

Comment: Are you sure you're not persisting the wrong token? Tokens do expire and occasionally you'll need to ask for another one. All the schema and the controller and all this other code is basically irrelevant as far as I can tell.

Comment: well, users are able to sign up/login correctly with no issues so doesn't that confirm that the token+secret are valid?

Comment: Are you only talking about new users, or existing users?

Comment: @normalocity, I researched into this yesterday as well as today and it says Twitter tokens do not expire. I'm talking about new and existing users when they try to post

Comment: fmendez... that fixed it. thank you SO much. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @johbones Btw, if you are already using an initialiser, why are you passing the credentials at creation? You should be able to just say: `Twitter::Client.new`

Comment: @fmendez, I may have to create a new thread on this later today, but do you know why my code is allowing everyone (whether they're authenticated using omniauth or not) to post to the same twitter account? I believe it may have something to do with way `def twitter` is set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
Twitter::Client.new(:token => provider.token, :secret => provider.secret)
```

into this

```
Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret)
```